# How attach only selected bones of the armature to the mesh?

Tags: rigging, parent

I am making a character and my whole rig is ready for skinning.

I have deformation and control bones. I want to create automatic weights only for deformation bones. Everytime when I have my bones selected (control bones are on a different layers) and hit **ctrl + P -> with automatic weights** I see that all my weight painting is messed up, because blender create vertex groups for all bones.

Ps. Control bones have deform option uncheck.

There was a similar question before but the answer in my case it didn't worked.
Also when I go to the Weight Paint mode of my mesh and click **Weights -> assign automatic from bones** it doesn't work.[image: deformation bones][image: control bones]

Comment: could you please share your file or at least a part of it? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: In weight paint mode you have to enable the vertex selection tool and select the verts what you want to assign. (In most cases you can select all).